# Wrap every 2 posts on a row

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using `Bootstrap`, I have a list of posts and I want to wrap every 2 posts on a row. Each post is wrapped on a `<div col>.` You can see live [here](https://miradasocial.es/category/actualidad/).

I tried with this but it wrap the row each one post:

```
<?php 
$num = 0;
// Check if there are any posts to display
if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
<?php
// The Loop
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
if($num%2) { 
echo "<div class='row' style='margin-bottom: 2.3em;''>";
}
?>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
  <h2 class="category-encabezado">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Enlace a <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
      <?php the_title(); ?>
    </a>
  </h2>
  <small>Hace 
    <?php echo human_time_diff( get_the_time('U'), current_time('timestamp') ) . ''; ?>
  </small>
  <div class="entry">
    <p>
      <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    </p>
    <?php
$my_shortcode = get_field('audio-field');
echo do_shortcode( $my_shortcode );
?>
  </div>
</div>
<?php
if($num %2) {
echo '</div>';
}
$num++
?>
<?php endwhile; // End Loop
?>
</div>
<?php
```

Comment: can you give us a better code style ? The code is not very clear @Pedro Corchero Murga

Comment: Updated for beautify the code.

Comment: Try this - I am not 100% sure but may work - Instead of incrementing $num after checking the condition to add </div>, do it before checking like this. <?php                   $num++;
if($num %2) {
echo '</div>';
}
?>  Also there is a typo - you are missing ; after $num++ in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put div.row Out of the Loop while